# sort_array order by a different column, Hive

Tags: sorting, hadoop, hive

I have two columns, one of products, and one of the dates they were bought. I am able to order the dates by applying the sort_array(dates) function, but I want to be able to sort_array(products) by the purchase date. 
Is there a way to do that in Hive?

Tablename is

```
ClientID    Product    Date
100    Shampoo    2016-01-02
101    Book    2016-02-04
100    Conditioner    2015-12-31
101    Bookmark    2016-07-10
100    Cream    2016-02-12
101    Book2    2016-01-03
```

Then, getting one row per customer:

```
select
clientID,
COLLECT_LIST(Product) as Prod_List,
sort_array(COLLECT_LIST(date)) as Date_Order
from tablename
group by 1;
```

As:

```
ClientID    Prod_List    Date_Order
100    ["Shampoo","Conditioner","Cream"]    ["2015-12-31","2016-01-02","2016-02-12"]
101    ["Book","Bookmark","Book2"]    ["2016-01-03","2016-02-04","2016-07-10"]
```

But what I want is the order of the products to be tied to the correct chronological order of purchases.

Comment: Do you have to use sort_array? Why not SORT BY products,dates?

Comment: @inquisitive_mind - it does not guarantee the order

Comment: Give data sample

Comment: Ah yes, the first step is grouping by the clientID, and then collapsing all the products they ever bought into an array (so it can be 1 row per customer). I want to ensure the products bought are in chronological order. 

select
clientid,
COLLECT_LIST(product),
sort_array(COLLECT_LIST(date))
from tablename
group by 1;

Comment: @inquisitive_mind thanks! But sort by does not collapse all items into 1 row

Comment: Put all the information in the post and add a data sample

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz adjusted the initial question to include a sample. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to do it using only built-in functions, but it is not a pretty site :-)

```
select      clientid
           ,split(regexp_replace(concat_ws(',',sort_array(collect_list(concat_ws(':',cast(date as string),product)))),'[^:]*:([^,]*(,|$))','$1'),',') as prod_list
           ,sort_array(collect_list(date)) as date_order

from        tablename 

group by    clientid
;
```

---

```
+----------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| clientid |             prod_list             |                date_order                |
+----------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|      100 | ["Conditioner","Shampoo","Cream"] | ["2015-12-31","2016-01-02","2016-02-12"] |
|      101 | ["Book2","Book","Bookmark"]       | ["2016-01-03","2016-02-04","2016-07-10"] |
+----------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: this worked like a charm! Over 4M records now ordered! Thank you!

Comment: Can it sort array with desc order in Hive SQL？